# Does putting the minus sign inside or outside the quote matter?

Tags: html, css, less

I've got PHP storm and I'm getting a red underline if I have this line:

```
height: calc(~'100% - '(@site-navbar-height + @site-menubar-height));
```

If I change that to the following, the error goes away:

```
height: calc(~'100% ' - (@site-navbar-height + @site-menubar-height));
```

Notice that I'm just moving the minus sign from inside the quote to outside the quote. Does it matter which way its put?

[**On this site**](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%5Cn%40site-navbar-height%3A%2010px%3B%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn.page-aside%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20height%3A%20calc(~'100%25%20-%20'%40site-navbar-height)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20width%3A%20calc(~'100%25'%20-%20%40site-navbar-height)%3B%5Cn%5Cn%7D%22%7D), both ways outputs the same thing:

Comment: It doesn't make any difference (I think), but the minus sign into the quote, it becomes more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the quote it is being treated as a string. I think it is confusing your linter because it doesn't see any mathematical expression (which is needed by `calc()`) causing the flag. Putting it outside the quote will treat it as a true operator.

Placing it outside the quote would be the syntactically correct way to do it.